# Triangle and altitudes

Tags: geometry

I need help with the following problem.

Given an acute triangle $ABC$. $BB_1$ and $ CC_1$ are the altitudes. If $\frac{B_1C_1}  {C_1B} = \sqrt 2$ and $\angle ACB=75^{\circ}$, find the angles $\angle ABC$ and $\angle BAC$

Comment: (-1) No efforts... once again

Comment: No efforts? How do you know that? I have been trying to solve it for a few hours already...

Comment: Actually, I've just  found $\angle BAC= 45$  and $\angle ABC=60$. Could anyone confirm it?

Comment: Well that's better

Comment: Your results are correct, you can write answer to your question. Other MSE users could benefit from it.